# global variables in a python web app (flask)

Tags: python, web-applications, flask

I am running the python web app that follows my question. When I run it from the command line everything works fine. It calls the **main** part of the program loads the xml file and whatever requests are subsequently made from the /search/term path my web app returns the right values. If however I run it from apache, the ***main*** is naturally not executed. How, in that case can I open the file once and then be able to make queries on it with every request? Is that even possible or should I load the data to a database in order to have this kind of persistence? Ideally I would like to avoid the complexity of db calls since I am doing simple string search operations.
Thanks in advance (code follows below)

Marinero

```
from flask import Flask
from classes import History
from xmlReader import xmlReader

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '<h1>Hello World!</h1>'

@app.route('/search/<term>')
def user(term):
    (resultCoords, resultTerms) = historyObj.searchForTerm(term)
    result = "<p>"
    for t in resultTerms:
        result = result + t.string + '<br>' 
    result = result + '</p>'
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    reader = xmlReader("web_history.xml")
    global historyList
    historyList = reader.getData()
    global historyObj
    historyObj = History(historyList)
    app.run()
```

Comment: Noob question: Why can't you remove all other statements from the `if __name__` block and have only `app.run()` within the if block?

Answer (score 0):

The problem of course is that when in the `reqest` context in Apache, the variables stored in the `app context` will not be available.

Here is a code snippet from Miguel Grinberg's excellent book on making variables globally available in the `request` context:

```
@main.app_context_processor
def inject_permissions():
    return dict(Permission=Permission)
```

So in your case something like

```
@app.app_context_context_processor
def inject_permissions():
    #return globals here
```

And then you should be able to access those files that were available in the app context in the request context.

Edit: Would comment but not enough rep

Someone more experienced with Flask is probably better able to answer the difference between our solutions but I'll give it a shot.

The only obvious difference between my implementation and yours is that the code will automatically run regardless of the context of the Flask app. This is obviously unneccessary in the `app_context`

There may also be additional problems once the app gets more complex (blueprints, different configurations) because the variables are being defined before anything else is so I would imagine modifying the global variables would be difficult.

Edit 2: Response to second comment: I looked at the book again and yes, that is the reasoning behind the pattern he uses:

> To avoid having to add a template argument in every render_template() call, a context >processor can be used. Context processors make variables globally available to all templates.

Comment: Thanks for replying FoxRocks. i just managed to make it work before seeing that you replied. In what way is my solution worse than yours? Mine seems simpler, but then again I am a noobie.

Comment: -> my app is now somewhat slower (on apache). Do you think my solution opens the file *every* time a request is made? That defeats the purpose and might make your solution better. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. @FoxRocks, should I prefer your method over mine? Any reasons? Greatly appreciated. The solution that worked for me was:

```
from flask import Flask
from classes import History
from xmlReader import xmlReader
from flask.ext.script import Manager

app = Flask(__name__)
manager = Manager(app)
globalString = "hello"
reader = xmlReader("web_history.xml")
global historyList
historyList = reader.getData()
global historyObj
historyObj = History(historyList)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '<h1>Hello World!</h1>'

@app.route('/search/<term>')
def user(term):
    (resultCoords, resultTerms) = historyObj.searchForTerm(term)
    result = "<p>"
    for t in resultTerms:
        result = result + t.string + '<br>' 
    result = result + '</p>'
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```